# Control software for the buck-boost dc/dc converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control, pid-controller

I have been developing control software for the cascaded buck-boost converter.

[image]

The main goal of that control software is to control the inductor current \$i_L\$ flowing from the voltage \$V_1\$ side into the voltage \$V_2\$ side in case:

- \$V_1>V_2\$ (buck mode)

[image]

- \$V_1<V_2\$ (boost mode)

[image]

As far as the control algorithm itself my first idea was to use the common current control loop for both the operating modes (buck and boost) and "duty cycle selector" block which determines the duty cycles for both the converter legs based on the currently active operatinge mode determined based on simple comparator with hysteresis

[image]

My question is whether the above described control algorithm is capable to control the inductor current (in case the PI controller is tuned appropriately) in case the \$V1 > V2\$ and at the same time in case \$V1 < V2\$. I will also appreciatee recommendation to some application notes or literature where I can find description of a standard way of control of the above mentioned power electronics converter.

Comment: Both converters can be run synchronously and so your 2nd and third diagrams are wrong/naïve. [Here's an earlier question you asked about it to remind you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511308/how-to-control-the-non-isolated-bidirectional-buck-boost-converter)

Comment: @Andyaka can you recommend me any application note or literature where I could find how to control the transition between buck and boost mode and vice verse?

Comment: I can't recommend literature because I know the theory. I'm sure there must be good literature about though. I do recommend that you operate synchronously and use MOSFETs instead of BJTs. In simple terms, when one voltage is greater than the other you use either buck or boost depending on which voltage is the source with the other acting as a straight bypass circuit.

Comment: You may be looking for "Switch Mode Power Supplies" by Christophe Basso. He's too modest to plug it himself, but he has been known to answer questions about the book here on SE.

Comment: @verbalkint - maybe you should take a look at this question?

Comment: Here's a strategy for managing the boost-buck transition 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276891380_DC_Active_Power_Filter_based_Hybrid_Energy_Source_for_Pulsed_Power_Loads